# GF specials and their attachment to characters

Tags: metafont

One for the obsolete file format anoraks—DEK doesn't seem to make this clear anywhere in the `gftodvi` source code—I *think* that GF specials apply to the character data that follows them and that anything between the last `eoc` and the `post` opcode would be global, but it appears that things like a `slantfont` special are attached to the first character in the font (interestingly, I could only find one Metafont source in my texmf tree that actually specified a `slantfont`). DEK is clear that MF never writes `xxx` opcodes inside a character, so I'm curious about the extent to which there are conventions around MF specials.